# Django: Unable to Apply Function View Decorator to Class Based View

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

I'm migrating from regular function based views, to class based views. One of the things that I couldn't migrate were the decorators I used. The decorator in question checks if the credentials of the current user are valid and then executes the decorated function:

```py
def custom_auth(function):

    @wraps(function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        # Logic for validating if user has correct credentials

        # Fetches the user that accessed the function
        user_object = User.objects.get(username=request_username)       
        
        # Try to execute the decorated function. If it fails, redirect
        # to previous page and show an error popup   
        try:
            return function(request, user=user_object, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            # Logic for displaying the popup
```

Previously I could just decorate my function by doing

```py
@custom_auth
def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # View logic
```

However, when I try to apply it to my class based view in the same way, I get an error saying `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given: user='username', view='cbvview'`

```py
@custom_auth
class CBV(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get request logic
```

I know that this is not the way you are supposed to apply the decorator, so I tried with different approaches. Either adding the decorator to `urls.py`, adding the `@method_decorator(custom_auth, name="dispatch")` or simply overriding the dispatch method, but none of them work. All of them give me the same error.

What could be the issue? Maybe I should use a custom mixin instead?

Comment: I think you should use `dispatch()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`@method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/utils/decorators/#method_decorator) like following:

```py
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(custom_auth,name="dispatch")
class CBV(View):
    
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      ...
```

### Edit:

Try to make your own mixin as class and inherit it to be used in `CBV` class so:

```py
class CustomAuthMixin:
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Logic for validating if user has correct credentials

        # Fetches the user that accessed the function
        user_instance = User.objects.get(username=request_username)       
        
        # Try to execute the decorated function. If it fails, redirect
        # to previous page and show an error popup   
        try:
            return super().dispatch(request, user=user_instance, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            # Logic for displaying the popup

class CBV(CustomAuthMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get request logic
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this, and the error message still pops up. I also tried actually including an override for the dispatch method under `class CBV` but to no avail as well

Comment: @Eddysanoli Let me check again.

Comment: @Eddysanoli What is this `request_username`, I think it will work by making a custom mixin.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. The funny thing was that my problem was not about this, but me simply not setting up the view in `urls.py` with the "as_view" method. Rookie mistake, but after sorting that out, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

from django docs  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

and there is no need to add the user to the function call in the decorator. It is already in the request

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work either. I even tried removing the `user=user_object` like you suggested but doesnt help either